# Angular SPA VS template project does not work correctly after deploying to remote IIS

Tags: visual-studio, angular, iis, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I installed SPA templates (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates`) and then created a basic Angular project using `dotnet new angular`. Running the project from Visual Studio worked fine locally both in IIS as well as IIS Express. But after deploying to a remote IIS (publishing from VS) I get the 403 errors as shown in the image below. The project is deployed to a subfolder of the site root. This should be easy to reproduce. What could be wrong?

[image: 403 HTTP errors]

Comment: I am not an expert and this may be something stupid that I ask. Can this be a proxy issue?

Comment: There are no proxies involved, so no. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.

Huh... there is a simple reason for this and I am hoping this will help somoene. As I am **not** publishing to site root, apparently some rewrite rules were too stict to mess up the routing of the sub-app. After writing some new rules to handle this new Angular app, things started working.